# Can anybody help with Stacking UV islands?

Tags: uv

I have a question about stacking islands on top of each other. In the image below they have the same amount of vertices, but are scaled a bit differently. Is there a way to make them the same and have them stack on top of each other?

I also own UVpackmaster.

[image]